# The shelveset could not be unshelved

Tags: tfs, shelveset, unshelve, gated-checkin

I'm using TFS 2013 to build an MVC application and while trying to do a check-in, sometimes, this error occurs.

[image: Error image]
This only happens when it's configured to do a Gated Check-in and when I turn it off, it just works, but sooner or later it comes back again.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** The problem is a PendChange permission in a transform of a config file. However, I'm checking the permissions and the user is "inherited allowed" to check-in the file.

Comment: Which one are you using? local or server workspace?  Also if you are using server workspace, what is the type of the lock? Is multiple checked out enabled in your project?

Comment: What's the changes included in the checkin? Is there any other error message included in the log?

Comment: @Eddie - MSFT, I have a suspicion that it only occurs when someone tries to do a check-in with only a config file change in it. Any clues? The only message that appears is the one from the print.

Comment: Can you provide some steps so that I can try to reproduce it at my side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, if you are using server workspace and enable multiple checked out. This maybe the root cause.

**Disable** the multiple checked out(***Team Explorer-Settings-Source Control-Check-out Settings***) and try it again.
[image]

Comment: Hi @Patrick-MSFT, here we use a local workspace, so I can't change this option.

Comment: Gated Check-in and when I turn it off, it just works, but sooner or later it comes back again. If you turn off the Gated Check-in, why the error come back again? There shouldn't be any shelveset generated and need to be unshelved.

Comment: I turn off the Gated Check-in so people can perform the check-in, because in this way it doesn't generate a shelveset. The problem comes back after I turn on the Gated Check-in again. I have a suspicion that it only occurs when someone tries to do a check-in with only a config file change in it. Any clues?

Answer (score -1):

In case all these solution fails. Check your build definition. It should point to the same branch in which you are working.